# Changing some instances of a color to another

Tags: gimp

I have this:

[image: Before]

and would like to create this:

[image: After]

```
 My thinking is that it can be done through the following methods; 
    1. Find a way to replace some of the white to gray at random.
    2.  Manage to select only some of the tiles at random.
```

However, I've not found a way to actually do either of my methods.

Do any of you to do it or have any other ideas of methods.

Thanks on beforehand.

Comment: Your thinking won't work.  GIMP and similar image editing software (such as Photoshop) can't make selections randomly or automatically.   The software has no built in artificial intelligence to make decisions. You will need to use the bucket fill tool or make selections manually, and fill them yourself.

Comment: *"GIMP [...]  can't make selections randomly [...]"*. Ah... Plenty of "random" tools in Gimp: all the "noise" stuff, plasma...  Check the source code of `Select>Distort` to see a very clever use of "spread noise".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Filters>Render>Clouds>Solid noise. Make sure the detail noise is smaller than your intended grid (both X and Y cursors to the right)
- Filters>Blur>Pixelize and give the size of your grid (20x20 here)
- Use the Threshold tool (changing the threshold will change the black/white ratio)

[image]

Another possibility is to use a QR-code generator, using random strings.